# Rewrite subdomain with variables

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm relatively new to rewrites and I've been trying this all day, but it's not working. I'm trying to redirect this:

```
users.domain.com/joe.smith
```

to this

```
domain.com/folder1/folder2/profile.php?firstname=joe&lastname=smith
```

(with joe and smith being variables)

I'd be ok with passing "joe.smith" as a variable and sorting it out php side, but I can't even get that to work. Here's what I have so far (just trying to pass one variable in this one).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^users\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) /folder1/folder2/profile.php?username=%1
```

I'd really appreciate any help! :) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks faa and @rekire for your quick replies. I'm still not managing to get it to work with either of those responses, but I'll keep tinkering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^users\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(.+) /folder1/folder2/profile.php?firstname=$1&lastname=$2
```